# Automating an update to a column from a change another column in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I am trying to update a ("Release Status") column to "Completed", when another column ("CMR Status") is changed to "Closed".

What I'm having problems with is the names of the actions I can take. When I select "Update Item", I get forced into entering required fields, when I'm only trying to target the two column statuses' above.

[image: Flow checker]

Comment: Please include an image of your current flow.  What is your trigger?

Answer (score 0):

The flow needs to have an action that reads the item properties. Depending on your flow, that could be the flow trigger item, or you could load the item in question with a `GetItem` step.

In the `UpdateItem` step you can then populate the required fields with the properties from that previous step. You only need to do that for required fields. If a field is not required and does not change in your update, you can leave it blank. Note that you need to delete any default values for Choice fields, so they appear blank; otherwise you will set the choice field to that default value.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.